# Need a specific operation to be performed on Fogbugz api

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I need to get some very specific information from the FogBugz API. Although I can spend time with the API documentation but I was just wondering if folks here had experience with it and might offer some help.

I need this information - for a given date range and a given person I want to know how much time he spent on the tickets.

So, we use the 'working on' feature a lot and I think we can get this info using this feature somehow. Not sure.

So what command/query should I be looking at?

Any suggestions/pointers would be helpful!

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FogBugz XML API](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api) can get you what you're looking for via the `listIntervals` command in the [Time Tracking section](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api#timeTracking):

> **cmd=listIntervals** - returns all TimeIntervals for a user. Any of the optional arguments serve to filter the results.
>
> Arguments
>
> - **ixPerson** (optional) - Specifies which user's intervals should be returned. If omitted, list intervals for the logged on user. If set
>     to 1, list intervals for all users. Note that you must be an
>     administrator to see time interval information for users other than
>     the logged on user.
> - **ixBug** (optional) - Specifies that only intervals associated with this bug should be returned.
> - **dtStart, dtEnd** (optional) - If dtStart and/or dtEnd are supplied, listIntervals will return intervals whose start date falls
>     between dtStart and dtEnd.

So the query you'd be using would look something like this:

`[your FogBugz url]/api.asp?token=[your XML API token]&cmd=listIntervals&ixPerson=[ixPerson you're interested in]&dtStart=[start date]&dtEnd=[end date]`

For future reference, there is a FogBugz-specific Q&A site: http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up using the following two queries - 1. [fogbugz url]?cmd=search&token=[xml api token]&q=editedBy:\"[person name]\" edited:[start date]..[end date]&cols=sTitle,dtLastUpdated,sStatus,sPersonAssignedTo,events,hrsElapsed AND 2. [fogbugz url]?cmd=listIntervals&token=[xml api token]&ixPerson=[fogbugz person id]&dtStart=[start date]&dtEnd=[end date]. After I have this all info, I use XDocument to query it for useful stuff I meed and some mixing and matching and I get my results all fine !  :)